# Java API Streams collecting stream in Map where value is a TreeSet

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

There is a `Student` class which has `name, surname, age` fields and getters for them.

Given a stream of `Student` objects.

How to invoke a `collect` method such that it will return `Map` where keys are `age` of `Student` and values are `TreeSet` which contain `surname` of students with such `age`.

I wanted to use `Collectors.toMap()`, but got stuck.

I thought I could do like this and pass the third parameter to `toMap` method:

```
stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getAge, Student::getSurname, new TreeSet<String>()))`.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Student::getAge,
                Collectors.mapping(
                      Student::getSurname, 
                      Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new))           
))
```

Answer (score 1):

Eugene has provided the best solution to what you want as it's the perfect job for the `groupingBy` collector.

Another solution using the `toMap` collector would be:

```
 Map<Integer, TreeSet<String>> collect = 
        students.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getAge,
                        s -> new TreeSet<>(Arrays.asList(s.getSurname())),
                        (l, l1) -> {
                            l.addAll(l1);
                            return l;
                        }));
```

Comment: For sure, this solution works. However mutability would cause a thread safety issue during parallelism ?

Comment: @zikzakjack nope, this is perfectly thread safe, each thread get its own container that are later merged.

Comment: I’d replace `Arrays.asList` with `Collections.singleton`…